# document array to array within aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

sub question from [matrix column combinations within aggregation pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48133315/matrix-column-combinations-within-aggregation-pipeline) ...

"$facet: Processes multiple aggregation pipelines within a single stage on the same set of input documents. Each sub-pipeline has its own field in the output document where its results are stored as an array of documents."

```js
var res = db.people.aggregate( [
  { $facet: {
   facetName1: [ { $match: { group: 1 } }, { $group: {_id: "$age"} }, { $sort: { _id: 1 } } ],
   facetName2: [ { $match: { group: 2 } }, { $group: {_id: "$age"} }, { $sort: { _id: 1 } } ],
   facetName3: [ { $match: { group: 3 } }, { $group: {_id: "$age"} }, { $sort: { _id: 1 } } ],
   facetName4: [ { $match: { group: 4 } }, { $group: {_id: "$age"} }, { $sort: { _id: 1 } } ],
   facetName5: [ { $match: { group: 5 } }, { $group: {_id: "$age"} }, { $sort: { _id: 1 } } ] }
  }
 ]
);
```

```js
{
  "_batch": [
    {
      "facetName1": [ { "_id": 22 }, { "_id": 23 }, { "_id": 26 }, { "_id": 40 } ],
      "facetName2": [ { "_id": 19 }, { "_id": 31 }, { "_id": 32 }, { "_id": 36 } ],
      "facetName3": [ { "_id": 21 }, { "_id": 24 }, { "_id": 28 } ],
      "facetName4": [ { "_id": 20 }, { "_id": 25 }, { "_id": 27 } ],
      "facetName5": [ { "_id": 18 }, { "_id": 29 }, { "_id": 37 } ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to take the sub-pipeline data and further process it to create the array:

```js
22,23,26,40
19,31,32,36
21, 24, 28
20, 25, 27
18, 29, 37
```

Have attempted this with a $project after the $facet, and a $group after $facet trying to manipulate the facetName1, facetName2, facetName3, facetName4, facetName5 data but have been singularly unsuccessful - these code attempts not worth posting.

Dropping out of the pipeline into js I can:

```js
var arr1 = [[],[],[],[],[]];

for(j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
  for(i= 0; i < res._batch[0]["facetName" + (j+1)].length; i++){ 
   arr1[j].push(res._batch[0]["facetName" + (j+1)][i]._id);       
  }
}

printjson(arr1);

[[22,23,26,40],[19,31,32,36],[21, 24, 28],[20, 25, 27],[18, 29, 37]]
```

Not sure if I am asking too much of Mongo Query Language as I am assuming the power of SQL Server stored procedures?

Thanks to Veeram for response - in Mongo 3.6.1 this gives "errmsg" : "The field 'ages' must be an accumulator object".

Referring back to original [matrix column combinations within aggregation pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48133315/matrix-column-combinations-within-aggregation-pipeline), I was trying $facet to try and simulate multiple table aliases as apparently collection aliases not allowed in Mongo.  I had constructed the people example as the real app is a multiplayer chess game where the data is potential moves and really complex. The people example wants to create workgroups picking a person from each group where the summed ages in the workgroup have to meet some criteria ... maybe a really bad example? However I am thinking that showing the sql code to do the same thing might be very helpful:

```js
select
   a.name,
   b.name,
   c.name,
   d.name,
   e.name,
   (a.age) + (b.age) + (c.age) + (d.age) + (e.age) as tot_len
from
   people a
   --
   cross join
      people b
   --
   cross join
      people c
   --
   cross join
      people d
   --
   cross join
      people e
where
   a.grp = 1 and
   b.grp = 2 and
   c.grp = 3 and
   d.grp = 4 and
   e.grp = 5 and
  (a.age + b.age + c.age + d.age + e.age) % 5 = 0
  -- (a.age + b.age + c.age + d.age + e.age) > 110 etc
  
  order by a.name, b.name, c.name, d.name, e.name
```

The result is:

```js
name name name name name tot_len
Alice      Arthur     Doris      Enid       James      155
Alice      Arthur     Freda      Enid       Jane       140
Alice      Arthur     Sue        Bob        Jane       135
Alice      Arthur     Sue        John       Jane       130
Alice      Mary       Doris      Bob        Jane       130
Alice      Mary       Doris      John       Jane       125
Alice      Mary       Freda      Bob        Julie      145
Alice      Mary       Freda      John       Julie      140
Alice      Mary       Sue        Enid       Jane       125
Alice      Ted        Doris      Enid       Jane       145
Alice      Ted        Freda      Bob        James      150
Alice      Ted        Freda      Enid       Julie      160
Alice      Ted        Freda      John       James      145
Alice      Ted        Sue        Bob        Julie      155
Alice      Ted        Sue        John       Julie      150
Alice      Verne      Doris      Enid       James      160
Alice      Verne      Freda      Enid       Jane       145
Alice      Verne      Sue        Bob        Jane       140
Alice      Verne      Sue        John       Jane       135
Brian      Arthur     Doris      Enid       Jane       130
Brian      Arthur     Freda      Bob        James      135
Brian      Arthur     Freda      Enid       Julie      145
Brian      Arthur     Freda      John       James      130
Brian      Arthur     Sue        Bob        Julie      140
Brian      Arthur     Sue        John       Julie      135
Brian      Mary       Doris      Bob        Julie      135
Brian      Mary       Doris      John       Julie      130
Brian      Mary       Freda      Enid       James      125
Brian      Mary       Sue        Bob        James      120
Brian      Mary       Sue        Enid       Julie      130
Brian      Mary       Sue        John       James      115
Brian      Ted        Doris      Bob        James      140
Brian      Ted        Doris      Enid       Julie      150
Brian      Ted        Doris      John       James      135
Brian      Ted        Freda      Bob        Jane       125
Brian      Ted        Freda      John       Jane       120
Brian      Ted        Sue        Enid       James      135
Brian      Verne      Doris      Enid       Jane       135
Brian      Verne      Freda      Bob        James      140
Brian      Verne      Freda      Enid       Julie      150
Brian      Verne      Freda      John       James      135
Brian      Verne      Sue        Bob        Julie      145
Brian      Verne      Sue        John       Julie      140
Fred       Arthur     Doris      Bob        James      135
Fred       Arthur     Doris      Enid       Julie      145
Fred       Arthur     Doris      John       James      130
Fred       Arthur     Freda      Bob        Jane       120
Fred       Arthur     Freda      John       Jane       115
Fred       Arthur     Sue        Enid       James      130
Fred       Mary       Doris      Enid       James      125
Fred       Mary       Freda      Enid       Jane       110
Fred       Mary       Sue        Bob        Jane       105
Fred       Mary       Sue        John       Jane       100
Fred       Ted        Doris      Bob        Jane       125
Fred       Ted        Doris      John       Jane       120
Fred       Ted        Freda      Bob        Julie      140
Fred       Ted        Freda      John       Julie      135
Fred       Ted        Sue        Enid       Jane       120
Fred       Verne      Doris      Bob        James      140
Fred       Verne      Doris      Enid       Julie      150
Fred       Verne      Doris      John       James      135
Fred       Verne      Freda      Bob        Jane       125
Fred       Verne      Freda      John       Jane       120
Fred       Verne      Sue        Enid       James      135
Mark       Arthur     Doris      Bob        Jane       125
Mark       Arthur     Doris      John       Jane       120
Mark       Arthur     Freda      Bob        Julie      140
Mark       Arthur     Freda      John       Julie      135
Mark       Arthur     Sue        Enid       Jane       120
Mark       Mary       Doris      Enid       Jane       115
Mark       Mary       Freda      Bob        James      120
Mark       Mary       Freda      Enid       Julie      130
Mark       Mary       Freda      John       James      115
Mark       Mary       Sue        Bob        Julie      125
Mark       Mary       Sue        John       Julie      120
Mark       Ted        Doris      Bob        Julie      145
Mark       Ted        Doris      John       Julie      140
Mark       Ted        Freda      Enid       James      135
Mark       Ted        Sue        Bob        James      130
Mark       Ted        Sue        Enid       Julie      140
Mark       Ted        Sue        John       James      125
Mark       Verne      Doris      Bob        Jane       130
Mark       Verne      Doris      John       Jane       125
Mark       Verne      Freda      Bob        Julie      145
Mark       Verne      Freda      John       Julie      140
Mark       Verne      Sue        Enid       Jane       125
```

Comment: Do you have to use $facet unless I'm something here ? I mean you can definitely simplify it to use other aggregation stages and get the expected output unless I missing something. Try this `db.people.aggregate( [ { $match: { group: {$in:[1,2,3,4,5] } }}, { $group: {_id: {group:"$group", age:"$age"} }}, { $sort: { "_id.age": 1 } }, { $group: {_id: null, ages:"$_id.age"} } ]);`

Comment: Sorry, I've fixed the query.`db.people.aggregate( [ { $match: { group: {$in:[1,2,3,4,5] } }}, { $group: {_id: {group:"$group", age:"$age"} }}, { $sort: { "_id.age": 1 } }, { $group: {_id: "$_id.group", ages:{"$push":"$_id.age"} } } ]);`